Python 3.12.7 module ssl has no attribute wrap_socket
Here is a sample of a python script:
import mysql.connector
...
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="********",
    database="mydatabase",
    auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

When I'm running this script with Python 3.12.7, I have the following error:
$ python3 my_script.py 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/my_script.py", line 580, in <module>
    function()
  File "/home/user/my_script.py", line 345, in function
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 173, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 102, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 735, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 250, in _open_connection
    self._do_auth(self._user, self._password,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 155, in _do_auth
    self._socket.switch_to_ssl(ssl_options.get('ca'),
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 427, in switch_to_ssl
    self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'ssl' has no attribute 'wrap_socket'

It looks like it is related to Python but I'm not sure.
I'm running this script under Ubuntu 24.10.
Do you have any ideas to fix this bug?

The module-level ssl.wrap_socket() was marked as deprecated in Python 3.7 and fully removed in Python 3.12. Programs should create a SSLContext using ssl.create_default_context() and use the context instance's .wrap_socket() method.
In other words, your mysql.connector has not been updated for Python 3.12 compatibility. According to MySQL docs you need mysql.connector version >=8.2.0 for Python 3.12.
You might have better luck using the MySQLdb module, which is available via pip as the "mysqlclient" package. It uses the same C libraries (libmysqlclient or libmariadbclient) and supports TLS.
